# How to space web pages uniformly in CSS with only <br/> and <b> tags?

Tags: html, css

How can i improve a formatting issue with my blogger blog pages (running into thousands)? I recently moved themes and the spacing is now not consistent on the posts. The pages only use br and b tags (no p in blogger by default -- I know!).

I removed additional br tags using br + br {display: none;}, thanks to this site, which helps. But there are places where there are only two br tags together and the gap looks completely closed. I see that some br tags have a space before them and some don't, so I'm not sure if that makes a difference? I also tried to improve the spacing using the b tag (as below). Using margins does not seem to have any effect on br.

So I have:

```
br + br {display: none;}

b 
{
display: block;
margin-bottom:5px; 
margin-top:10px; 
}
```

Here's a sample page: http://www.thetweedpig.com/2017/05/manchester-swagger.html

It doesn't look good. How to space web pages uniformly in CSS with only br and b tags?

Comment: b tags are inline and only function is to bold text, br tags are the only concern

Comment: Those 2 rulesets are hindrances. The first one basically makes a pair of br into one br, very useless. The second one shouldn't exist it's inane. Use br sparingly, and use `margin-bottom` **or** ` margin-top` on elements but don't mix them, just pick one and stick with it.

Comment: You're right, but on some pages, if I don't put the 'display: block;' for b, the b ends up on the same line as the preceding text. Maybe that's still a br issue I need to resolve, but I'm stuck.

Comment: The br + br hides all br tags greater than one -- quite useful for the number of pages I am trying to format from CSS - thousands.

Comment: *"the b ends up on the same line as the preceding text"* That's the way b is supposed to work, that's called `inline`. If you must use a block, replace those b with a p or div. I'd like to help you resolve your problem but that's just too much to sort through. If someone was to hire me to fix it, I'd tear it all down.

Comment: To answer one part of your question: Yes, Wordpress by default converts line breaks in its editor into `<br />` tags in its front end display.

Comment: Thanks for the offer Zero. I'll let you know if I get tired of trying to sort it out.

Comment: Thanks Mike. yes -- discovering that I should have been more disciplined with formatting to begin with.